# How to parse xml file which is having another xml file as a tag in java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse one xml file whose one of the tag/node having another xml file as a data so how  could i parse that file.following is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
<URL>
<RequestUrl>http://www.google.com
</RequestUrl>
<RequestData>
"<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><PingMe xmlns="visum.Server.Service" id="o0" c:root="1"><Data i:type="d:string">ping</Data></PingMe></v:Body></v:Envelope>"
</RequestData>
</company>
```

when i am going to parse the above xml file & retrieve the xml file under Request Data tag it is not returning me whole string of another xml file but only blank string so how should i proceed for that?

Comment: That's not valid XML. If you want a XML inside another XML (quite ugly, in general) it should be escaped or in a CDATA section.

Comment: sorry the xml previously added was wrong now it is corrected please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse this instead. You have to use CDATA in order for your extra "XML" to not be interpreted.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
<URL>
    <RequestUrl>http://www.google.com</RequestUrl>
    <RequestData>
    <![CDATA[
        <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                 xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><PingMe xmlns="visum.Server.Service" id="o0" c:root="1"><Data i:type="d:string">ping</Data></PingMe></v:Body></v:Envelope>
    ]]>
    </RequestData>
</URL>
</company>
```

Comment: actually my code is parsing the another tag i.e. request url perfectly so i think the parsing code is correct

Comment: i am still stick to that issue please help me